# How do I send a value from a Microsoft Bot to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework

I need to send a string from the MessagesController in a Microsoft Framework Bot to a script written in JS. The string contains the value of a secret for a bot we are hosting which is inactive (not in use). Is there a way to send a string from an Azure hosted bot?

Edit: I have tried to create a method which returns a string but cannot retrieve it through a url (sitename.azurewebsites.net/api/messages/methodname), I cannot use Jsonresult or Actionresult as the bot isn't MVC.

More info: We have set up 5 bots which set themselves as being active (in a chat session) or inactive (not in a chat session). We know if a bot is active or not by the values set in a database. There is a stored procedure in the database which returns a direct line secret for an inactive bot. What I want to do is send this secret (string) from the database to the JavaScript so we can generate a bot dynamically. The problem is, we do not want to connect to the database from the JS on the front end, instead we want to get the secret from a bot (any bot). Therefore I would like to get a string value from the MessagesController into JavaScript from the hosted bot on azure.

Thanks

Edit2:

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetString()
        {
            return Ok("it worked");
        }

returns BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!
```

Comment: Have you tried the standard [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646996/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-script-from-within-another-node-js-script)?

Comment: Sorry the bot is written in .NET and is called via plain JavaScript on the website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the following:

> I need to send a string from the MessagesController in a Microsoft
>   Framework Bot to a script written in JS.

By using the backchannel capability of the webchat channel. Based on your query I assume your are using this channel here.

To get more information about the backchannel, have a look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel).
The idea is to send an event from your bot code, that will be received by the JS on the client side:

The client JavaScript also listens for a specific event from the bot. In their sample they show the ability to change a color on the client side, based on an event sent by the bot:

```
botConnection.activity$
    .filter(activity => activity.type === "event" && activity.name === "changeBackground")
    .subscribe(activity => changeBackgroundColor(activity.value))
```

You can use the following to send the secret you require and activate the right bot.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nicolas. I am making decent progress with this suggestion, however I am having trouble returning an activity through the backchannel. The event is posted fine to the Post method in the MessagesController, however I am struggling to find a way to return the activity with the value to the listener, any suggestions? The backchannel example on the link you gave is in node.js. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a snippet of the code I am currently on which is not being sent from the bot:
`if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
            {
                Activity Secret = activity.CreateReply();
                Secret.Type = ActivityTypes.Event;
                Secret.Name = "changeSecret";
                Secret.Value = GetInactiveBotSecret();
                var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

                await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(Secret);
                // rootDialog.EndConnection();
            }`

Comment: Aha! I have found it, the line to send the event is rootDialog.PostEvent(Secret);. The event has been picked up by the JavaScript and I have retrieved the value successfully. Thank you for your help, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: "The backchannel example on the link you gave is in node.js." it wasn't, it was a sample to process an event from client JS to bot. On your side, you just have to send an Activity of type Event with the Secret value inside, like you commented. I missed more of your implementation to provide a better complete answer

Comment: My apologies, I meant in the section "The provided backchannel sample requires a bot which can send and receive specific event activities. Follow the instructions here to deploy such a bot." of the link, you are right the bit you sent was from client JS to bot. Thanks again for the help.