# Returning back to the calling script after running a node script from within another node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, function

I am trying to call a node script from another node script. I am using execSync for that purpose.
My code goes as follows:

**scriptA.js**

```
function a () {
  for(i=0,i<names.length;i++){
    var a = 'somestring'
    var b = 'someobj'
    child_process.execSync(`node scriptB.js ${a} '${b}' >> run.log &`);
  }
}
```

**scriptB.js**

```
function b () {
   //logical executions happen here
}
```

So function b is executing but I need this to be done for names.length times.
So the control flow should go back to the scriptA's loop and increments and call scriptB again.

How do I achieve this?

Should just a 'return' statement do?

My code stops after scriptB finishes and not coming back to scriptA for the next loop.

Comment: What is that ampersand (&) at the end of your execSync for?

Comment: to make the process run in the background @LeoDog896

Comment: Do you want the `execSync` statement to run asynchronously? If so, you may be interested in `exec` instead of `execSync`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a Node.js script from within another Node.js script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646996/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-script-from-within-another-node-js-script)

Comment: No, @Joel I checked several other such questions. So my question is not about how to call another script but how to get the called script back to the calling script. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I see that my process ID which is created while executing the scriptB.js is still present when I did ps aux and is not killed. What should be possibly done in that case? What are the possible reasons that a process is not still over ? Could this be due to the async/await and promise used inside the code? @LeoDog896

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding process.exit(0) at the end in scriptB.js as it is the most straightforward approach to exit a child process manually after all its execution gets over.

Ideally, a child process should return back to the parent process (calling process) after its execution but I found that process.exit() can also be done to kill it in the edge cases.

```
function b () {
   //logical executions happen here
process.exit(0) //if everything is completed as expected
}
```

Thanks a lot.